# mongoDB .toArray() slower on some aggregations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with n documents. The documents look something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/dragon/",
  "meta": {
    "title": "SpaceX - Dragon",
    "description": "SpaceX designs, manufactures and launches advanced rockets and spacecraft. The company was founded in 2002 to revolutionize space technology, with the ultimate goal of enabling people to live on other planets.",
    "keywords": []
  },
  "rank": 1.073810573484715,
}
```

I search for documents with the following:

```
main('apple');

async function main(searchTerm) {

    const agg = [{
        '$match': {
            '$text': {
                '$search': searchTerm
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'rank': {
                '$add': [{
                    '$meta': 'textScore'
                }, '$rank']
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': {
            'rank': -1
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 7
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'meta': 1,
            'rank': 1
        }
    }];

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(
        'mongodb://localhost:8080', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
    );

    const coll = client.db('coll').collection('docs');
    const cursor = coll.aggregate(agg);
    const result = await cursor.toArray();
    
    return result;

}
```

Now this works great with some searches for example: spacex, where all this is done in less than a second, with the actual aggregation taking no time at all. With other searches such as 'apple', the process takes way too long, so I eventually give up. It's the .toArray() part that actually takes up time, the rest works exactly as expected. Why does .toArray() take so long on some searches but not all?

This is what explain shows for 'mongodb':

```
{ stages: 
   [ { '$cursor': 
        { queryPlanner: 
           { plannerVersion: 1,
             namespace: 'geezeIt.docs',
             indexFilterSet: false,
             parsedQuery: 
              { '$text': 
                 { '$search': 'mongodb',
                   '$language': 'english',
                   '$caseSensitive': false,
                   '$diacriticSensitive': false } },
             queryHash: '3F7B44B0',
             planCacheKey: 'AC2F8FA3',
             winningPlan: 
              { stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
                transformBy: { _id: 1, imgs: 1, meta: 1, rank: 1 },
                inputStage: 
                 { stage: 'TEXT',
                   indexPrefix: {},
                   indexName: 'geezeDex',
                   parsedTextQuery: 
                    { terms: [ 'mongodb' ],
                      negatedTerms: [],
                      phrases: [],
                      negatedPhrases: [] },
                   textIndexVersion: 3,
                   inputStage: 
                    { stage: 'TEXT_MATCH',
                      inputStage: 
                       { stage: 'TEXT_OR',
                         inputStage: 
                          { stage: 'IXSCAN',
                            keyPattern: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1 },
                            indexName: 'geezeDex',
                            isMultiKey: true,
                            isUnique: false,
                            isSparse: false,
                            isPartial: false,
                            indexVersion: 2,
                            direction: 'backward',
                            indexBounds: {} } } } } },
             rejectedPlans: [] },
          executionStats: 
           { executionSuccess: true,
             nReturned: 253,
             executionTimeMillis: 11,
             totalKeysExamined: 253,
             totalDocsExamined: 253,
             executionStages: 
              { stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
                nReturned: 253,
                executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9,
                works: 509,
                advanced: 253,
                needTime: 255,
                needYield: 0,
                saveState: 1,
                restoreState: 1,
                isEOF: 1,
                transformBy: { _id: 1, imgs: 1, meta: 1, rank: 1 },
                inputStage: 
                 { stage: 'TEXT',
                   nReturned: 253,
                   executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
                   works: 509,
                   advanced: 253,
                   needTime: 255,
                   needYield: 0,
                   saveState: 1,
                   restoreState: 1,
                   isEOF: 1,
                   indexPrefix: {},
                   indexName: 'geezeDex',
                   parsedTextQuery: 
                    { terms: [ 'mongodb' ],
                      negatedTerms: [],
                      phrases: [],
                      negatedPhrases: [] },
                   textIndexVersion: 3,
                   inputStage: 
                    { stage: 'TEXT_MATCH',
                      nReturned: 253,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
                      works: 509,
                      advanced: 253,
                      needTime: 255,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 1,
                      restoreState: 1,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      docsRejected: 0,
                      inputStage: 
                       { stage: 'TEXT_OR',
                         nReturned: 253,
                         executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
                         works: 509,
                         advanced: 253,
                         needTime: 255,
                         needYield: 0,
                         saveState: 1,
                         restoreState: 1,
                         isEOF: 1,
                         docsExamined: 253,
                         inputStage: 
                          { stage: 'IXSCAN',
                            nReturned: 253,
                            executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
                            works: 254,
                            advanced: 253,
                            needTime: 0,
                            needYield: 0,
                            saveState: 1,
                            restoreState: 1,
                            isEOF: 1,
                            keyPattern: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1 },
                            indexName: 'geezeDex',
                            isMultiKey: true,
                            isUnique: false,
                            isSparse: false,
                            isPartial: false,
                            indexVersion: 2,
                            direction: 'backward',
                            indexBounds: {},
                            keysExamined: 253,
                            seeks: 1,
                            dupsTested: 253,
                            dupsDropped: 0 } } } } },
             allPlansExecution: [] } },
       nReturned: 253,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9 },
     { '$addFields': { rank: { '$add': [ { '$meta': 'textScore' }, '$rank' ] } },
       nReturned: 253,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9 },
     { '$sort': { sortKey: { rank: -1 }, limit: 7 },
       nReturned: 7,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9 },
     { '$project': { _id: true, imgs: true, meta: true, rank: true },
       nReturned: 7,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9 } ],
  serverInfo: 
   { host: 'ubuntu',
     port: 27017,
     version: '4.4.15',
     gitVersion: 'bc17cf2c788c5dda2801a090ea79da5ff7d5fac9' },
  ok: 1 }
```

for other terms such as 'apple', I wasn't able to get the explain plan as it takes too long...

Comment: I think that calling `toArray()` starts the actual aggregation query, everything before that is just setting it up. If you have a lot more documents matching the `apple` query, it'll naturally take longer to load them (also, `toArray()` will load _all_ results into memory first).

Comment: @robertklep , so how would I perform the aggregation, and then load the results into ram?

Comment: First of all it might not even fit into RAM. Run the aggregation in mongosh, or any other client and check how many results are there. Check slow log. All queries longer than 100 millis are logged to `system.profile` collection unless you changed the threshold.

Comment: @AlexBlex , the aggregation limits the results to 7? The documents are not large? If I perform the aggregation and then perform .toArray, how would this not fit in ram?

Comment: fair point, I missed the limit. Still I'd check the profiler. What does `.explain()` say?

Comment: @AlexBlex I added the explain plan for one search.

Comment: Try .explain() with $text match stage only. The problem is likely with number of matching documents. `nReturned: 253` in this case. The $sort stage have to do in-memory sort for all results before you apply $limit. In any case, your exercise with .explain() proves the problem is not with .toArray(), but with the query itself. It is slow.